# Why ASP.NET Core Identity Cookie is not working across domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-identity

I set some cookie options in my ASP.NET Core Identity, to include a couple of subdomains:

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(identityOptionsCookies =>
        {
            identityOptionsCookies.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
            identityOptionsCookies.Cookie.Name = "ExampleToken";
        });
```

Based on this configuration, I login via this subdomain:

```
api.accounts.example.com
```

And I check that I am authenticated, using this API call:

```
api.accounts.example.com/identity/isAuthenticated => returns true
```

Now I go to another subdomain, using the same configuration for Startup.cs, and I'm not authenticated anymore:

```
api.user.example.com/teacher/list => redirects me to /Accounts/Login
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Your provided codes should work according to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-cookies-across-subdomains - Questions: a) How does the cookie look like in your browser? Are all cookie settings correct? b) Is the cookie send in request to api.accounts.example.com? c) Are both domains the same app instance or separate deployments? (If separate: How is data protection configured?)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen, What do you mean how cookie looks like? Cookie is sent back in request to API and I can verify it by debugging `HttpContext.Request.Cookies`. These are separate deployments, across separate servers.

Comment: If you've verified that the request to api.user.example.com contains the correct cookie, I guess the problem is that it's running on different servers. Identity will create a ticket in local file system of api.accounts and so api.user can't find this ticket. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0 for details on how to configure it to work with multiple servers.

Answer (score -1):

identityOptionsCookies.Cookie.Domain = "*.example.com";